# Read integer from numeric cell using Apache POI in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls, numberformatexception

I have an application which reads xls sheet using apache poi.  When the cell has numeric value, i read it by row.getCell(i).getNumericValue(). But it returns floating point digit. like if the cell value is 1, it returns 1.0. Can i convert it to int ? Any helpwould be appreciated. I tried Integer.parseInt(value)- but it throws NumberFormat exception.Any help is appreciated.Here is the pseudo code:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        switch(cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                String value= String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                int intVal = Integer.parseInt(value)-->>throws Exception
```

Comment: Got it, fetch the value as double as conert to int :Double val = cell.getNumericCellValue(); val.intValue will give the answer

Comment: Here's a simple solution:

`double dval = row.getCell(cellCounter, XSSFRow.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK ).getNumericCellValue();
System.out.println(new Integer(new Double(dval).intValue()).toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read int value as string apache poi using simple steps

First count rows in sheets using below method

```
private  int getRowCount(Sheet currentSheet) {
        int rowCount = 0;
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = currentSheet.iterator();

        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {  
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            if(row == null || row.getCell(0) == null || row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().trim().equals("") || row.getCell(0).toString().trim().equals("") 
                    || row.getCell(0).getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
                break;
            }
            else
                rowCount=rowCount + 1;
        }       
        return rowCount;
    }
```

Then use below code in your method

```
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("c:/test.xls");
    Sheet marksSheet = (Sheet) workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
            int zoneLastCount = 0;
            if(marksSheet !=null ) {
                zoneLastCount = getRowCount(marksSheet);
            }
    int zone = zoneLastCount-1;
    int column=1

    for(int i = 0; i < zone; i++) {         
        Row currentrow = marksSheet.getRow(i);
        double year = Double.parseDouble(currentrow.getCell(columnno).toString());
        int year1 = (int)year;
        String str = String.valueOf(year1);
    }
```

Comment: This code will fail for numeric cells, as you're trying to read the string value without checking/ensuring that your cells are numeric

Comment: now its working , your cell value general also its working no need to check

Answer (score 33):

Numbers in Excel are (except for a few edge cases) stored as floating point numbers. Floating point numbers in Java, when formatted as a string, are printed with a trailing decimal point, as you're seeing

Assuming what you really wanted was "give me a string that looks like what Excel shows for this cell", then *do not* call cell.toString(). This will not give you what you want in most cases

Instead, you need to use the [DataFormatter class](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html), which provides methods which read the Excel format rules applied to a cell, then re-creates (as best it can) those in Java

Your code should be:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("c:/test.xls");
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for (Row row : sheet) {
     Cell cell = row.getcell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
     if(cell!=null) {
          String value = fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
          if (! value.trim().isEmpty()) {
             System.out.println("Cell as string is " + value);
          }
     }
 }
```

You may notice I've also fixed a bunch of other stuff as well....!

Comment: Very clean approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
  // to extract the exact numerical value either integer/double
  DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
  Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
  while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
      case NUMERIC:
        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
          Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
          DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
          //DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
          fetchedRow.add(dateFormat.format(date));
        } else {
          fetchedRow.add(fmt.formatCellValue(cell));
        }
        rowEmpty = false;
        break;
      case STRING:
        fetchedRow.add(cell.toString());
        rowEmpty = false;
        break;
      case BOOLEAN:
        fetchedRow.add(cell.toString());
        rowEmpty = false;
        break;
      case FORMULA:
        fetchedRow.add(Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
        rowEmpty = false;
        break;
      case BLANK:
        fetchedRow.add("");
        break;
    }
  }
  if (!rowEmpty) {
    allRows.add(fetchedRow.toArray(new String[0]));
    count++;
  }
  if (count >= limit) {
    break;
  }
}
return allRows;
```

}

eaxmple to read limitted no.of rows on and use DataFormatter to give exact numeric value either integer/ double value. This will work.

Answer (score 1):

Someone might find this hack useful:

```
cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
int value = Integer.parseInt(cell.getStringCellValue());
```

Remember you alter the cell type here, so be sure this does not cause any side effect. In a single-threaded app you can just read the type before and restore it after.

Comment: `setCellType` is deprecated in new versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following (to obtain a long):

```
long value = (long) currentCell.getNumericValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just type cast `float` to `int` like :

```
String value = String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellCpt);

String cellContent = "";
if (cell != null) {
    cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
    cellContent = fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below implementation worked for me:

```
private Object getValue(Cell cell) {
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            return String.valueOf((int) cell.getNumericCellValue());
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            return cell.getBooleanCellValue();
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            return cell.getErrorCellValue();
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            return cell.getCellFormula();
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```