# I am trying to pass parameters from excel sheet to my website signup page, all fields working fine except mobile number field

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xssf

I am trying to pass parameters from excel sheet to my website signup page, all fields working fine except mobile number field. Its reading as 1.234567890 but my actual data is 1234567890. How can i solve this problem?

**Here is my code:**

```java
public class ReadExcelData {
    WebDriver driver;

    String name;
    String state;
    String address;
    String pincode;
    String city;
    String date;
    String month;
    String year;
    String agencyName;
    String pancardNo;
    String pancardHolder;
    String contactNumber;
    String emailid;
    String password;
    String confirmPassword;

    public ReadExcelData(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    public void readExcel() throws IOException{

        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("D://TestData.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sh1=wb.getSheetAt(0);

                XSSFRow row=sh1.getRow(1);
                name=cellToString(row.getCell(0));
                state=cellToString(row.getCell(1));
                address=cellToString(row.getCell(2));
                pincode=cellToString(row.getCell(3));
                city=cellToString(row.getCell(4));
                month=cellToString(row.getCell(6));
                year=cellToString(row.getCell(7));*/
                agencyName=cellToString(row.getCell(5));
                pancardNo=cellToString(row.getCell(6));
                pancardHolder=cellToString(row.getCell(7));
                contactNumber=cellToString(row.getCell(8));
                emailid=cellToString(row.getCell(9));
                password=cellToString(row.getCell(10));
                confirmPassword=cellToString(row.getCell(11));

                RegisterWithUsPage signup=new RegisterWithUsPage(driver);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_Name).sendKeys(name);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_State).sendKeys(state);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_State).sendKeys(state);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_Address).sendKeys(address);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_Pincode).sendKeys(pincode);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_City).sendKeys(city);
                Select ddl1=new Select(driver.findElement(signup.ddl_Date));
                ddl1.selectByVisibleText("12");
                Select ddl2=new Select(driver.findElement(signup.ddl_Month));
                ddl2.selectByVisibleText("9");
                Select ddl3=new Select(driver.findElement(signup.ddl_Year));
                ddl3.selectByVisibleText("1992");               driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_AgencyName).sendKeys(agencyName);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_PanCardNo).sendKeys(pancardNo);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_PanCardHolder).sendKeys(pancardHolder);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_ContactNo).sendKeys(contactNumber);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_EmailId).sendKeys(emailid);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_Password).sendKeys(password);
                driver.findElement(signup.txtbox_RetypePassword).sendKeys(confirmPassword);

        wb.close();
    }
    private String cellToString(XSSFCell cell) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int type;
        Object result;
        type=cell.getCellType();
        switch(type){
            case 0:
                result=cell.getNumericCellValue();
                break;
            case 1:
                result=cell.getStringCellValue();
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("There are no support for this type of cell");
        }       
        return result.toString();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Instead of providing numeric value, try with string only!

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771412/read-integer-from-numeric-cell-using-apache-poi-in-java

Comment: How about try to change cell format in excel to "Text"?

Comment: Pass it as a string from the excel sheet. Just add an apostrophe before the number in the excel sheet. Example: '1234567890

Comment: Hi Shank,I added apostrophe before number but it's not working

Comment: Hi Alice,I changed the cell format to 'Text' in excel,It's working fine.Thank you very much Alice.